# javascript moving through json object how to tell if an element is present

Tags: javascript, json

I am iterating through a json object and it fails due to an extra element.

see code bellow

```
{
"rootLayout":"main",
"layoutDescriptions":[
      {
        "type":"Panel",
        "label":"Repeating Groups By Subform",
        "layout":"SimpleForm",
        "content":[
          { "type":"label", "constraint":"newline", "text":"Contacts" },
          { "type":"repeatableGroup", "property":"contacts", "contentRef":"ContactSubForm" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type":"Panel",
        "label":"",
        "container" : {
          "type":"Panel",
          "layout":"SimpleForm",
          "content":[
            { "type":"label", "constraint":"newline", "text":"Contact Name" },
            { "type":"ListView", "property":"contactName", "listProps":["contactName","telephone","email"] }
          ]
        }
      },
```

it fails on the second element in the array I am using the following to get  my results

```
data.layoutDescriptions[0].container.content[i].content
```

I know its stopping because on

```
data.layoutDescriptions[0].container.content[1].content
```

it expects

```
data.layoutDescriptions[0].container.content[1].container.content
```

so my question is how do I say if container is present do this else do this.

I am trying this at the moment which does not work.

```
    var contentObjects = data.layoutDescriptions[0].container.content[1].content;
if(contentObjects.container){
                 alert("container exists");
                 }
                         else{
                  alert("nope");
                  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, actually your question has nothing to do with JSON, only how to test the existence of properties of JavaScript objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript test for existence of nested object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use hasOwnProperty to check if an object has its own property exists:

```
 var contentObjects = data.layoutDescriptions[0].container.content[1];
 if(contentObjects.hasOwnProperty('container'){
     alert("container exists");
 }
 else{
     alert("nope");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that not every object inside the array `layoutDescriptions` has the attribute `container`. When you loop over the first object, it looks for `container`, doesn't find anything, and then searches for `content` on `undefined`, throwing an error.

Also, inside `data.layoutDescriptions[0].container.content[1]`, you don't have a `content` attribute. `contentObjects` gets set to `undefined` and therefore `contentObjects.container` will fail.